# SQL Server 2012 import/export wizard not showing at all

Tags: sql-server-2012, import, azure-sql-database, export

So I have access of two databases that are stored in Azure, and using SQL Server 2012 to access them. All I need to do is copy a table from one db and duplicate and create it in another. I keep reading everywhere that all you have to do to bring up the import and export wizard and right click the db, go to tasks and then the option for the wizard will be right there. But I cannot find it in the menu anywhere! I feel like I'm crazy or something, but I hope this is a simple solution! Here is a screenshot of what I am seeing. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

[image: SQL Server 2012 available tasks]

Comment: I'd recommend using the latest version of SSMS when working with Azure. Try downloading the latest build of SSMS 2016 here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The import/export wizard is not showing because it is not available for Azure SQL. Even if you downloaded the latest version of SSMS, you shouldn't see it.

You are in a different environment that how on-premise SQL Server databases work. In that Azure SQL does not support using cross database queries. So doing an `insert into or select insert` are not going to work.

Depending on how big the table is, your easiest thing to do is using the script object wizard and just include the data. Then just run that under the destination database.

If you need to do this on a routine basis then look at the data sync services Azure offers.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone's answers, but I have found a workaround! I basically had to manually add the Import and Export Wizard to SQL Server manually. I had to go to Tools > External Tools (see screenshot).

[image: External Tools]

Then the external tools dialog opens up (see screenshot).

[image: External Tools Dialog]

You can then provide a title, but in the command field you can enter in the path of the Import and Export executable. It was found here for me `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTSWizard.exe` 
although I'd imagine it could be in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTSWizard.exe` for some people as well. Then click ok. It should now be an option under tools right above where you clicked 'External Tools'. Then the Export and Import Wizard came up and it worked like a charm. I was able to follow through the wizard and transfer the tables between two Azure databases.